# exponential null operator

Tags: operator-theory, exponential-function, banach-algebras

In $A$ banach algebra with unit, and $X\in A$. if i define

$e^X=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}X^n$

why $e^0=Id$ , i am aassuming $O^0=Id $ with $0$ null operator

thanks

Comment: $0^n=0$ for all $n$ and $1+0+0+0+... = 1$.

Comment: mmm, so i took definition on arveson book, so definition what say $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}X^n = Id + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}X^n$   , don't understand where appear $Id$

Comment: It is just the first term, by definition. In the analytic functional calculus a constant evaluated at an operator is defined to be the identity operator times that constant. In your case $1$ is the first term of the McLaurin series of the exponential. So $1$ evaluated at the operator $0$, gives the identity operator multiplied by $1$.

Comment: ah thanks now undesrtand, si took sucesion $\{x_n\}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
Id & \hbox{   if n=0 } \\
\frac{1}{n}T^n & \hbox{if }n >  0 
\end{matrix}\right.$, this is absolute convergence and $A$ is Banach so serie converge

Answer (score 1):

Since$$e^X=\operatorname{Id}+X+\frac{X^2}{2!}+\frac{X^3}{3!}+\cdots,$$then$$e^0=\operatorname{Id}+0+\frac{0^2}{2!}+\frac{0^3}{3!}+\cdots=\operatorname{Id}.$$